# Android Timer in Service

Tags: android, timer, countdowntimer, timertask, stopwatch

Hi plan to develop and android countdown timer app for that activity with start and stop button when user click start button display timer countdown and user go to remaining activities even tho the timer is running background if user click stop then only stop the timer.

how can i run the timer in service and update the time to textview in activity android.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can. Ill give you a code sample that I used a long time ago. Keep in mind that this is not using  buttons, but it will give you a general idea how to do it. This code updates a ActionBar MenuItem with the current countdown value

This is the service:

```
public class CountDownTimerService extends Service {
static long TIME_LIMIT = 300000;
CountDownTimer Count;



@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    Count = new CountDownTimer(TIME_LIMIT, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long seconds = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
            String time = String.format("%02d:%02d", (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 60));

            Intent i = new Intent("COUNTDOWN_UPDATED");
            i.putExtra("countdown",time);

            sendBroadcast(i);
            //coundownTimer.setTitle(millisUntilFinished / 1000);

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            //coundownTimer.setTitle("Sedned!");
            Intent i = new Intent("COUNTDOWN_UPDATED");
            i.putExtra("countdown","Sent!");

            sendBroadcast(i);
            //Log.d("COUNTDOWN", "FINISH!");
            stopSelf();

        }
    };

    Count.start();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Count.cancel();
    super.onDestroy();
}}
```

This is the necessary code you need to have in your activity where you want to update the TextView:

```
startService(new Intent(context, CountDownTimerService.class));
registerReceiver(uiUpdated, new IntentFilter("COUNTDOWN_UPDATED"));
//Log.d("SERVICE", "STARTED!");


private BroadcastReceiver uiUpdated = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         //This is the part where I get the timer value from the service and I update it every second, because I send the data from the service every second. The coundtdownTimer is a MenuItem
        countdownTimer.setTitle(intent.getExtras().getString("countdown"));

    }
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @developer.android no problem. Feel free to vote up or anything. Share the love :)

Comment: @Aksiom. May i want you answer me? I want to have a control on screen ON?OFF with CountDownTimer as here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38613564/3671748